# Splitting perl array into separate arguments in qx operator

Tags: perl

I am trying to pass an array of arguments to the `qx` operator. Consider

```
my @files=qw(A.txt B.txt);
print qx/ls "@files"/;
```

This gives error:

```
ls: cannot access A.txt B.txt: No such file or directory
```

whereas substituting the array arguments explicitly:

```
print qx/ls A.txt B.txt/;
```

works fine. How can I pass a perl array to the `qx` operator such that each array element becomes a separate argument to the shell command?

Comment: Do you have file named A.txt and B.txt in current dir. If not this is expected error message of ls

Comment: @Tejas: that's the error message for a file called "A.txt B.txt", not for two files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the quotes, what you have is as if you typed `ls "A.txt B.txt"` in your shell.

```
print qx/ls @files/;
```

Warning: this doesn't work if you have files with spaces in their name in your array. You could single-quote those individually, but that doesn't sound like a good idea and handling all special chars is bound to break at some point. At which point I'd suggest not using an external program at all, use Perl features instead.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, using

```
qx/ls @files/;
```

is enough.

`@files` will be interpolated in the argument (which is a string) of `qx//`, there is no need to put it in a string.

If any element of your `@files` has space, then `qx/ls @files/` would not work. For example, the following code

```
my @files=('A.txt', 'B.txt', 'C .txt');
print qx/ls @files/;
```

will give these errors:

```
ls: .txt: No such file or directory
ls: A.txt: No such file or directory
ls: B.txt: No such file or directory
ls: C: No such file or directory
```

This could be fixed by quoting each element of `@files`, one way to achieve that is

```
my @files=('A.txt', 'B.txt', 'C .txt');

my $files;
$files .= " \Q$_" for @files;

print qx/ls $files/;
```

Another way is using `map`:

```
my @files=('A.txt', 'B.txt', 'C .txt');
@files = map { "\Q$_" } @files;
print qx/ls @files/;
```

The above code will give the following errors (as expected)

```
ls: A.txt: No such file or directory
ls: B.txt: No such file or directory
ls: C .txt: No such file or directory
```

---

Update:

`\Q` cannot handle embedded newline in file name, as pointed out by @choroba. Possible fix of this problem, `\'$_\'`, cannot handle embedded single quote. It looks like we need to combine them together:

```
my @files=('A.txt', 'B.txt', 'C .txt', "D\t.txt", "E\n.txt", "F'.txt", 'G".txt');

my $files;
$files .= m/\n/ ? " \'$_\'" : " \Q$_" for @files;

print qx/ls $files/;
```

This will give the following expected errors

```
ls: A.txt: No such file or directory
ls: B.txt: No such file or directory
ls: C .txt: No such file or directory
ls: D\t.txt: No such file or directory
ls: E\n.txt: No such file or directory
ls: F'.txt: No such file or directory
ls: G".txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Just a nitpick: It doesn't work for filenames with a newline.